# Ansible upgrades packages where it should not

Tags: ansible, redhat, yum

I have the following snippet:

```
---
- name: Install common packages
  yum:
    name: "{{  default_packages  }}"
    state: installed
  tags:
    - utils
    - packages
  when: "'satellite' not in group_names"
```

Variable for packages is as follows:

```
---
default_packages:
  - vim
  - yum-utils
  - rsync
  - telnet
```

But every time when there is a new package available from the list of "default_packages" Ansible upgrades it. I do not know why this is happening. State is installed and not set to latest. What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question and add 1) the content of the `default_packages` variable 2) a demo run in debug mode (`-vvv`) showing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

The packages that were always being upgraded were:

- vim-common
- vim-enhanced

I´ve defined "vim" in default packages. Now I´ve put vim-common and vim-enhanced in the default_packages and ansible is no longer upgrading.